# How to make elements of a webpage appear bigger in mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to build a responsive design for my webpage, but when I resize it, the elements are getting smaller.

Is there any way to make elements appear with a reasonable size in mobile browsers?

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #EAEAEF;
}

.cover {
  width: 840px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  right: 2%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cover">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Indeed there is a way.  Unfortunately we can't explain it too well unless we have some code to go by.  Please post your code here or go to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and paste the code there and share a link to the page.

Comment: Ok give me a second please @trav

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/h7zusanh/1/ @trav

Comment: your fiddle didn't explain anything about your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `viewport` for your webpage.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Add above on top of your webpage.

Comment: I did add this to my web page but didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Then share your webpage html and css